# Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'iTextSharp.text.SimpleTable' error

Tags: vb.net, html-to-pdf

I am using Visual Studio Pro 2005 trying to access iTextSharp.dll to convert HTML to PDF. The problem is that VS will not recognize the DLL returning this message:

> "Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'iTextSharp.text' doesn't
>   contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace
>   or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make
>   sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases."

This prevents any access to the object in my .Net VB code. iTextSharp version is 5.4.0 I downloaded today.

The problem is in both the components needed:

- Imports iTextSharp.text
- Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access a class using the full class name with namespace? Try `dim doc as iTextSharp.text.Document`. Also make sure you have a reference to the dll. You said you are using VS2005 - what version of .NET Framework is your project?

Comment: Dan, the .Net version is 2.5 which is the version for VS 2005. I had imported as per the examples given in a few similar examples in .Net VB. I have also used the .Net C# section and recompiled the DLL so I had a version match to only have the same error. I would be able to make some progress if it would recognize and provide access to the classes. Just getting access to the object in the first step would help a lot! :) The problem is I cannot access any part of the items in the iTextSharp object with .Net blocking it because of this error.

Comment: Continued: Attempting what you suggest only results in "Type ItextSharp.text.Document is not defined." error. So until .Net accepts the iTextSharp class as a whole no part of it will be accessible.

Comment: The dll I got from itextsharp is framework version 2.*. I made a new project and set the framework version to 2.0. I can access everything in the `iTextSharp` namespace. Try doing that in a new project. Does that work?

Comment: Thank you Dan. A small clue is all I needed. I was able to do as you did and it worked. I am tearing apart .Net at every level inside and out to compare both web projects to find out why my current project which is extensive, does not accept the iTextSharp while a new created web project will. I will post the answer when I find it. It was not in the web.config or the registry settings I has searched out so far. Current project will not list the iTextSharp in the References though it will create the bin and put it in.

Comment: Later... Results: I could not find anything that was in any accessible .Net files and storage to find a difference. So time to drop back and punt. I renamed the original folder, created a new folder and created a new web project in it and I first created the reference to iTextSharp and it worked. I copied in all of my prior project files folders and web references except Web.Config and prior sln files. I added lines for Databases from old web.config. Rebuilt the website and all worked well. Now I have proper and complete access to the iTextSharp object. Problem Resolved! On to implement it...

Comment: One other correction, I am working in .Net 2.0 not 2.5 as I posted in the first answer to Dan.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with CuteFM32.dll. The reference in the VB.NET project was pointing to `\obj\debug\interop.cuteformcolib.dll` but I think that when I ran the Build > Clean solution command it removed the dll and thus the reference was no longer valid. Note that 'Copy Local' was set to False for the reference to this DLL.

Fortunately simply removing and adding the reference worked for me but I had to turn on 'Show All files' in order to see that the imported DLL was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the reference works with a new project, make a new project and add all your classes, forms, etc., checking that the reference still works as you go. Either you will add everything and the problem is solved, or you will find what created issues.